# Initializing Constant with global variable

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to initialize a `constant` with global variable in my `angularJS` like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp')
.constant('test1', myTest.test1)
.constant('test2', myTest.test2);
```

The problem is sometimes global variable `myTest` is not available due to which it throws an error that `myTest is not defined`. I have tried this also:

```
.constant('test1', angular.isDefined(myTest)?myTest.test1:'')
.constant('test2', angular.isDefined(myTest)?myTest.test2:'')
```

But it still throws the same error. Is there any workout to this?

Comment: is myTest available in window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.isDefined` will not work if there is referenceError.

You may need to use:

```
.constant('test1', typeof myTest != "undefined"? myTest.test1 : "");
```

It's because of ReferenceError.

Better You include your angular code below the file which is setting the `myTest` property.

if script.js is setting your myTest object, then

```
window.myTest = {
   test1 : "Some value"
}
```

Then insert your angular app script below it,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp')
.constant('test1', myTest.test1)
.constant('test2', myTest.test2);
```

In this case, it will be always defined.

Comment: You know what i was typing the same typeof operator :-P
Now +1 for you Bingo :-)

Comment: @codelearner angular.isDefined is also throw error in case variable is not defined .Only javascript typeof operator manage this king of erro :)

Answer (score 0):

you can put your global constant in your html file inside of script tag before anything else loads like this

script 
        var test1= test1|| 'some value'; 

  script